# Lazy loading with JPA on @ManyToOne

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, lazy-loading

I have a project with Spring Boot, and I cannot make lazy loading work. I have 2 entities: `Question` and `Answer`. A question can have many answers.
What I want is, when I try to get an answer, to get only the answer without the question. And also, if I want both, to have this possibility.

What I did, is I added in application.yml: spring.jpa.open-in-view: true.
The `Answer` entity is like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mst_ans_answer", schema = "lquest_sc")
public class Answer implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "lquest_sc.mst_ans_answer_ans_lqs_id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator( name = "lquest_sc.mst_ans_answer_ans_lqs_id_seq", sequenceName = "lquest_sc.mst_ans_answer_ans_lqs_id_seq")
    @Column(name = "ans_lqs_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "qst_lqs_id")
    private int questionId;

    @Column(name = "ans_text")
    private String text;


    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "qst_lqs_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Question question;

    //getters and setters
}
```

The `Question` entity is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mst_qst_question", schema = "lquest_sc")
public class Question implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "lquest_sc.mst_qst_question_qst_lqs_id_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "lquest_sc.mst_qst_question_qst_lqs_id_seq", sequenceName = "lquest_sc.mst_qst_question_qst_lqs_id_seq")
@Column(name = "qst_lqs_id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "qst_title")
private String title;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "question")
@OrderBy("order asc")
private Set<Answer> answers = new HashSet<Answer>();


//getters and setters here
```

The call in the controller is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/questionId/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Answer> listAll( @PathVariable("id") int id ){
    List<Answer> answers = answerRepository.findByEnabledAndQuestionIdOrderByOrderAsc(1,id);
    return answers;
}
```

and the repository is

```
public interface AnswerRepository extends JpaRepository<Answer, Long> {
    List<Answer> findByEnabledAndQuestionIdOrderByOrderAsc(int enabled,int questionId);
}
```

The problem is that in the controller, when I try to evaluate
`answers.get(0).getQuestion()`, I receive the entity of Question, with the properties filled with `null` values and the error `Method threw 'org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException' exception. Cannot evaluate Question_$$_jvst5b6_1.toString()`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Bodgan like Many to one mapping in Answer entity ,have you written Question entity with OnetoMany mapping?

Comment: Can you please update your Question Entity also

Comment: i did. and i readed that i had to add @transactional ? is this needed? and where to add, inside controller, or inside AnswerRepository?

Comment: in repository you need to add the @transactional i.e inside the impl class of repository where you have written your business logic.

Comment: is the same. i have added at the end of the post the error that appear! (it was and at the beginning of posting but i forgot to post it)

Comment: @bogdan have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why `spring.jpa.open-in-view = true` is not working in your case. Maybe the `OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor`does not get triggered or the thread has been left, when you are evaluating the `Question`. Or you have an older version which just does not support it.

Lazy loading works only inside of a transaction. A solution could be -
 as @Pradeep already gave you the hint - to use `@Tranactional` inside a business logic class.

Even if you put the `@Transactional` inside your repository it will not work, because you have to put the annotation on top of the method where you are trying to evaluate `answers.get(0).getQuestion()`.

Furthermore I advise you not to call your repository from the controller directly, but to use a service layer, where you put your business logic.

---

### Example implementation

This is only a example implementation to show you how to structure your application and what the important keywords are. Also note, that you can either use `@Inject` or `@Autowired`. When you have implemented your logic, just inject the service into your controller and use it there.

AnswerService.java

```
public interface AnswerService {
   List<Answer> findByEnabledAndQuestionIdOrderByOrderAsc(int enabled, Long id);
}
```

AnswerServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class AnswerServiceImpl implements AnswerService {

    private AnswerRepository answerRepository;

    @Inject
    public AnswerServiceImpl(AnswerRepository answerRepository) {
        this.answerRepository = answerRepository;
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public List<Answer> findByEnabledAndQuestionIdOrderByOrderAsc(int enabled, Long id) {
        List<Answer> answerList = findByEnabledAndQuestionIdOrderByOrderAsc(int enabled,int questionId);

        // do your lazy loading here
        // because you are still in the same transactional context

        // return the list
        return answerList;
    }
}
```

Comment: 10x for your comment. my mistake, was that, i was looking with the inspector from intellijidea, and there, if i evaluate the local variable questions, that holds the answers list, there, the question was null. but after that, if i try to do an inspection of answers.get(0).getQuestion, in debugger a new call to database apear and gets the question details. so, the lazy operation is done ok. now, the problem is, if i try to get the list of questions, automatically gets and the list of answers and this is not ok, because, it should load only if i do this: questions.get(0).getAnswers()